# Click on button to open select options list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Is this even possible to open drop down list with options of  item by click on the  in js/jquery? Could You help with this, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Tkshz/?

If the var X is equal to 0 it means the list is visible so it hides the list. If the var X is equal to 1 it means the list isn't visible so it shows the list. The HTML isn't anything special, just a regular list.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var x = 0;

function dropDown(){
    if(x == 0){
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display="none";
        x = 1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display="block";
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="dropDown()">Show options</button>
<ul id="dropdown">
    <li><a href="google.com">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="google.com">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="google.com">Option 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="google.com">Option 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please set my answer as correct answer if it was what you were looking for.